# Optimal Scaling HMC proof

Tags: markov-chain-montecarlo, optimal-scaling, hamiltonian-monte-carlo

I'm reading the paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1001.4460.pdf

I get very confused when reading the author proof of the theorem (4.2)

Here are few points.

(1) The expected squared jump distance is computed as $$\mathcal{SJD} = \mathbb{E}[(q_d(t+\delta) - q_d)^2]$$

Where

$q_d(t+\delta) - q_d   \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{w.p. } 1-\lambda_d\delta + \mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^2) \\
    (q^{N(t)+1}-q^{N(t)})^2 &  \text{w.p. } \lambda_d\delta + \mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^2)  \\
    (q^{N(t)+1+j}-q^{N(t)})^2 & \text{w.p. } \mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^{j+1})
  \end{cases}$

Then, take the expectation of $q_d(t+\delta) - q_d$;

We should have  $\mathcal{SJD} = (q^{N(t)+1}-q^{N(t)})^2(\lambda_d\delta + \mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^2) ) + \sum_{j\ge 1}  (q^{N(t)+1+j}-q^{N(t)})^2\mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^{j+1})$.

But the author gives

$$\mathcal{SJD} = \mathbb{E}[(q^{N(t)+1}-q^{N(t)})^2](\lambda_d\delta + \mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^2) ) + \sum_{j\ge 1}  \mathbb{E}[(q^{N(t)+1+j}-q^{N(t)})^2]\mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^{j+1})$$

(2) I don't know where how does author derive the following relations

$$\mathbb{E}[(q^{N(t)+1+j}-q^{N(t)})^2] \le \Big( \sum_{k=1}^{j+1}|q^{N(t)+k} - q^{N(t)+k-1}|_{L2} \Big)^2 = (j+1)^2\mathbb{E}[(q^{n+1}-q^n)^2]$$

(3) The author states that $$d^{5/4}\sum_{j\ge 1}  \mathbb{E}[(q^{N(t)+1+j}-q^{N(t)})^2]\mathcal{O}((\lambda_d\delta)^{j+1})$$ has the same order in $d$ as

$$ \lambda_d^2 d^{5/4}\sum_{j\ge1}(j+1)^2\mathcal{O}(\lambda_d)^{j-1} = \mathcal{O}(\lambda_d) $$

but I couldn't be able to see why that the second equation is $\mathcal{O}(\lambda_d)$

Any helps. Thanks